# jquery and css active menu not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Demo](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/mreiI/)
After clicking the menu does not change under the color! 
**HTML**

```
<div class="p_menu_wrap">
  <div class="p_menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="">Link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.p_menu_wrap {
    float:left;
    width:979px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#fff;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 3px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
     border:1px solid #d8dbdf;
    }
.p_menu {
    width:580px;
    height:40px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    color:#fff;
    }
.p_menu li a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#000;
}
.p_menu li  {
  cursor:pointer;

}
.p_menu ul {
 list-style-type:none;
 float:left;
 text-decoration:none;
  line-height:40px;
  margin:0px;
}
.p_menu ul li {
 width:auto;
  padding:10px;
  height:40px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#000;
  display: inline;
  margin-left:20px;
     font-family:'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
}
.active {
 border-bottom:3px solid #b70000; 

}
```

**JS**

```
$('.p_menu li a').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
var $p = $('.p_menu li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $p.removeClass('active').filter(this).addClass('active');
});
```

`var $p` is a cache for menu items, so you don't requery DOM again and again.

I also added `preventDefault()` to avoid page flickering because of reload.

#### Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cqIDK

Comment: thanks for reply but it is not working. After clicking the menu does not change under the color!

Answer (score 1):

Your active `class` is actually on your `li` and not your anchor.

Use this instead. http://jsfiddle.net/AhqMD/2/

```
$('.p_menu li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.p_menu li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply but it is not working. After clicking the menu does not change under the color!

Comment: O_o Check that fiddle link